# Print the string only, when it is 10x the same

Tags: python

I have made a face recognition camera with Jetson Nano.
I have also made the Python function which returns me the recognized person name as a string every ~1s.

This is the simple test code:

```
from face import scanned_name

while True:
    print(scanned_name())
```

OUTPUT:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Unknown
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
Lukas Smith
Pavol Bujna
None
None
None
None
None
Benjamin Moose
Charlie Grey
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Pavol Bujna
Charlie Grey
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

As you can see, it's working quite fine when looking directly at the camera (9x Pavol Bujna).
When coming or leaving the camera, it's printing sometimes random names.

That's why I'm trying to filter that out, only when the same name will be detected let's say 10x, it will print it. So in this case, will print my name (Pavol Bujna) just once.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if scanned_name() == "10x the same string":
    print(scanned_name())
elif scanned_name() == None:
    print("Camera ready")
else:
    print("Recognizing face")
```

I don't know how to do that "10x the same string" part. I have tried to append it each time to the list, and then compare if every item in a list is the same, but that wasn't working well.

Comment: You need to keep track of the `last_scanned_name` and the `last_scanned_name_count`

Comment: "I have tried to append it each time to the list, and then compare if every item in a list is the same, but that wasn't working well." Since that is basically how to do it (perhaps using a ``deque`` for efficiency), please [edit] the question to show the code. Note that as your question is basically "select repeated occurrences from a stream", the use-case *and volume of description* of having a camera and image recognition appears irrelevant. You might want to reread the [mcve] help page.

Comment: A `deque` with a `maxlen` of `10` is what you're looking for. From there, `if len(set(my_deque)) == 1` will give you your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will print name that was scanned 10 times in a row

```
n_consec_scans_to_print = 10
consec_scanned_names_count = 0
last_scanned_name = None
while True:
    current_scanned_name = scanned_name()
    if current_scanned_name == last_scanned_name:
        consec_scanned_names_count += 1
        if consec_scanned_names_count == n_consec_scans_to_print:
            print(current_scanned_name)
            last_scanned_name = None
            consec_scanned_names_count = 0
    else:
        last_scanned_name = current_scanned_name
        consec_scanned_names_count = 0
```

**EDIT**
I don't know how `scanned_name()` works. So I advice you to consider handling the case when this function returns object that is incomparable with string

Comment: perfect! this is working for me :) Thanks

Comment: @PavolBujna glad I could help. Please mark this as accepted answer if this solves your question

Comment: Might not be so critical, but in your code, if `None` is repeated 10 times it will be printed as well (possible scenario according to the OP's output)

Comment: @Tomerikoo I guess that's up to OP whether he needs that behaviour. In some cases it might be usefull.

Comment: yes, that's fine, I can deal with the None, later on, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use a deque of length 10 and check if there is only one name in the queue, which is not `'None'`. This will only print the found name once (the first time it is encountered 10 times in a row):

```
from collections import deque

# names = list-of-your-names

queue = deque(maxlen=10)

found = False
for name in names:
    queue.append(name)
    if len(set(queue)) == 1 and name != 'None':
        if not found:
            found = True
            print(name)
    else:
        found = False
```

`names` can also be something which is iterable and generates the nameson the fly (e.g. a generator), it doesn't have to be a list, like for example:

```
def gen_name():
    import time
    while True:
        name = guess_name_from_image()
        yield name
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your code as follow :**

```
from face import scanned_name

same_string = []
while True:
    if not scanned_name() == None: 
        same_string += scanned_name()
        #"10x the same string" part.
        if same_string.count(scanned_name()) == 10:
            print(scanned_name())
        else:
            print("Recognizing face")
    else:
        print("Camera ready")
```

Comment: This will only store every *third to fourth* result. One is consumed by each ``if``, and one by the ``print``.

Comment: I believe, this is checking only if there is None and count the length of the list. But nothing is checking if all the items in the list are the same. 

If the List is:

[Pavol Bujna, Tom Smith, Pavol Bujna, Tom Smith, Pavol Bujna, Pavol Bujna, Pavol Bujna, Pavol Bujna, Pavol Bujna, Pavol Bujna]

It will print Pavol Bujna, but that's not true because of Tom Smith. Am I right?

Comment: Assuming `scanned_name()` returns a string, `same_string += scanned_name()` will not give the effect you're expecting (i.e. `same_string += "tomer"` will give `['t', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'r']`)